# How do I setup exim to send emails from mutiple domains?

Tags: exim

I have a centos 5 box running exim.  The box hosts many domain names which send outgoing email.  The problem is that the emails show that the email is coming the box's hostname (say x.com), rather than from each domain name (y.com and z.com).  How can I set this up so that an email sent from y.com actually says that it's coming from y.com?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the host name in the `Received:` header this is correct behavior.  Just add an MX record for all your domains referencing the box's hostname.  Also consider adding SPF records to the domains.  If your server is Internet facing, it needs a static address, and it IP address should have a PTR record returning its FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name).

If you are asking about what recipients see in their mail clients this is determined by the mail user-agent sending the message: If it puts the appropriate `From:` or `Reply-to:` headers in the outgoing e-mail, these should show up appropriately when the email is read.
For exim you can put entries in `/etc/email-addresses` to change the default domain and/or name for particular users.

Comment: There's a lot of information here - many thanks but I'm still flailing. So let's say the server name is a.com and it has a static IP address.  On the same box, I host b.com at a different IP address.  I send out emails from, say, admin@b.com, but in my email client, it says Received: from a.com, presumably because that's the main IP address of the box.  So should I somehow be telling exim to send the email from the IP address of b.com?

Comment: No, but you should add an MX record for b.com pointing to a.com.  Also make sure that the PTR record for a.com's IP address resolves to a.com.